# Убрать панель уведомлений

Tags: android

Можно ли убрать панель где дата, уведомления отображаются? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В манифесте:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Или программно:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да можно. Надо выставить:

```
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33aaccbb")));
```

Где цвет задается в формате ARGB (`#33aaccbb`) - первый байт показывает прозрачность, остальные на RGB цвета.

P.S. В первой версии вопрос был о прозрачности экшн бара :)

Comment: выкидывает ошибку. Я скрыл вообще экшнбар и установил тулбар в качестве его

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference

Comment: Ну если `actionBar==null` то я не виноват - научитесь его извлекать правильно!

Comment: попробую разобраться. Наверное я где-то ошибся.

Comment: написал так, но не меняется прозрачность 
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33aaccbb")));